# Cluster validity measures

Tags: r, clustering

For my thesis assignment I need to perform a cluster analysis on a high dimensional data set containing purchase data from a retail store (+500 dimensions). The ultimate goal is to detect clusters of customers. After applying several cluster algorithms I want to check the validity of my clusters.
However, for most of the validity measures in R they require a dist object(similarity or distance matrix) as input parameter. Since it's a large dataset with +- 500 000 rows ... it's impossible to calculate the dist object without retrieving memory issues.

Can someone help me to calculate the dist object or suggest me some useful validity measures? At the moment I'm only applying calinhara (Calinski-Harabasz)  from the package FPC which is working decent for large datasets, but my ultimate goal is to compare Calinski-Harabasz with other measures.

Comment: First of all, I think you need to specify the algorithms you have applied. Next, unsupervised cluster analysis is an exploratory technique. Unless you have prior groupings against which you can *validate* or confirm your results, it won't be possible to do this. You can, however, leverage measures of the internal consistency of your results using train vs test datasets and cross-validation to check the solution's ability to recover the original assignments...kind of like a rate of misclassification. The results with the best (lowest) error rate would "win."